# C++ Program - input text stream

Tags: c++, file-io, io

I am new to C++ and I have been given an example program that is supposed to be able to count the occurrences of each printable non-whitespace character in a given input text stream.

Apparently, I am meant to do something with command arguments, however I tried this and I was getting no output.

Here is the program:

CharacterCounter.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class CharacterCounter
{
private:
    int fTotalNumberOfCharacters;
    int fCharacterCounts[256];

public:
  CharacterCounter();

  void count( unsigned char aCharacter );

  friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& aOStream, 
                               const CharacterCounter& aCharacterCounter );
};
```

CharacterCounter.cpp:

```
#include "CharacterCounter.h"

using namespace std;

CharacterCounter::CharacterCounter(): fTotalNumberOfCharacters( 0 ),
                                  fCharacterCounts()
{}

void CharacterCounter::count( unsigned char aCharacter )
{
    fCharacterCounts[aCharacter]++;
    fTotalNumberOfCharacters++;
}

ostream& operator<<( ostream& aOStream, const CharacterCounter& aCharacterCounter )
{
    aOStream << "Character counts for " 
             << aCharacterCounter.fTotalNumberOfCharacters << " characters:"<< endl;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 256; i++ )
    {
        if ( aCharacterCounter.fCharacterCounts[i] != 0 )
        {
            aOStream << (char)i << ":\t" << aCharacterCounter.fCharacterCounts[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    return aOStream;
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "CharacterCounter.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    CharacterCounter lCounter;

    unsigned char lChar;

    while ( cin >> lChar )
    {
        lCounter.count( lChar );
    }

    cout << lCounter;

    return 0;
}
```

So, basically what I am asking is how can I modify this program, or make it so that it accepts a string of text (or something similar) and counts the occurrence of each character?

Comment: What exactly are you asking about, how to use command line arguments (there are thousands of tutorials and examples all over the Internet)? How to distinguish letters, digits, whitespace characters ([this characters classification reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte#Character_classification) should help)? Or something else? Please elaborate. And please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), if you haven't done it yet.

Comment: Also note that `(char)i` is bad because of two reasons: The first is that not all characters in your range are printable; The second because you should not use C-style casting in C++ (use `static_cast` instead, *if* the character is printable).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::getline` to allow input of a line from `std::cin`, and then process it in a way similar to what you already have. For simplicity I:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::map<char, size_t> count;

    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);

    for (char i : s)
    {
        ++count[i];
    }

    for (auto i : count)
    {
        std::cout << i.first  << " : " << i.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Online [here](http://ideone.com/AjcpKT)

Answer (score 0):

It's actually extremely simple if you think about it:

```
CharacterCounter count_string_chars( const std::string& line )
{
    CharacterCounter counter;
    for( std::size_t i = 0; i < line.size(); ++i )
    {
        counter.count( line.at(i) );
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get string as argument :

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    CharacterCounter lCounter;

    string str;
    if (argc >= 2)
    {
       std::string temp(argv[1]);
       str = temp;
    }

   for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
   {
        lCounter.count( str[i]);
   }
}
```